# Using strstr to find all instances of substring results in weird string formatting

Tags: c, string, strstr

I'm making a web scraper and i'm at the point where I need to parse the incoming data. Everything was going fine until I had to find all instances of a substring in a string. I was able to get something working but it doesn't give me the full string I want (which is a full `<p></p>` tag).

```
done = 0;

while (done == 0) {
    if ((findSpan = strstr(serverResp, "<p")) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", findSpan);
        if ((findSpanEnd = strstr(findSpan, "</p>")) != NULL) {
            strcpy(serverResp, findSpanEnd);
            strcpy(findSpanEnd+4, "");
            printf("after end tag formattng %s\n", findSpan);
        }
    } else {
        done = 1;
    }
}
```

After end tag formatting should give me a result along the lines of `<p>insert text here</p>` but instead, I get something like this:

```
        <p>This should be printed</p>
        <h3>ignore</h3>
        <p>and so should this</p>
    </body>
</html>

after end tag formatting <p>This should be printed</p>
        <h3>ignore</h3>
        <p>and so should this</p>
    </body>
</html>

after end tag formatting dy>
</html>
```

The site's code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>ignore this</h1>
        <p>This should be printed</p>
        <h3>ignore</h3>
        <p>and so should this</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `strcpy(serverResp, findSpanEnd)` has overlapping source and destination strings.  This is not allowed.  Why do you even need that, instead of simply `serverResp = findSpanEnd`?  The latter is a pointer assignment, of course.  It does not copy the string contents.  But not only can you almost certainly work with that, it's probably a lot faster, too.

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but when i assign findSpanEnd to serverResp, whatever happens to findSpanEnd also happens to serverResp, which i dont want

Comment: Your `strcpy()` moves that data in the string that `findSpan` is pointing in to.  The pointer value in `findSpan` doesn't change, but you move the data around inside that string.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to say "no" or "of course".  Do be careful to distinguish between the pointers and the data to which they point.  After the suggested assignment, both pointers point to the same data, so changes made to that data via one will be visible via the other.  But the pointers themselves are still distinct -- what happens to one happens only to that one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I looked into this further and it seems like when strcpy(findSpanEnd+4, ""); runs and then strcpy(serverResp, findSpanEnd); runs, the data from findSpanEnd is actually removing data from serverResp. I can't figure out how or why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if ((findSpanEnd = strstr(findSpan, "</p>")) != NULL) {
            strcpy(serverResp, findSpanEnd);
```

This makes no sense. `strstr` finds `"</p>"` as requested; however you can't pass that to `strcpy` like that. `strstr` doesn't allocate a new string at all; it only returns the location within the old one.

A routine to print out all `<p>` tags would look like this (note that this assumes no nested `<p>` tags):

```
    for (char *ptr = serverResp; ptr = strstr(ptr, "<p");)
    {
        char *finger = strchr(ptr, '>');
        if (!finger) break;
        ++finger;
        ptr = strstr(finger, "</p>");
        if (!ptr) {
            fwrite(finger, 1, strlen(finger), stdout);
        } else {
            fwrite(finger, 1, ptr - finger, stdout);
        }
        fputs("\r\n", stdout);
    }
```

The technique: the call to `strstr` in the for loop locates the next `<p>` tag, `strchr` finds the end of it, then another `strstr` finds the closing `</p>` Because the return pointers are into the originating string, we use `fwrite` instead of `printf` to produce output.

Comment: This worked but would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69: Better?

Comment: also, how does the ptr-finger thing work

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69: Well if you subtract the two pointers, you get the number of characters between them.